# How to chain javascript hide/show function for each div ID?

Tags: javascript

I have many `<p>`s with the same function.

```js
document.getElementById("minus").onclick = function() {
  functionHide()
};

function functionHide() {
  document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("minus").style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("plus").onclick = function() {
  functionShow()
};

function functionShow() {
  document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("minus").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#plus {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#minus {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.floatright {
  float: right
}

.w50 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="w50">

  <p>What paperwork do I need to complete to file for divorce ?
    <span class="floatright inlineb" id="minus">-&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="floatright inlineb" id="plus">+</span>
  </p>

  <p>How do I change my custody and suport orders ?
    <span class="floatright inlineb" id="minus">-&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="floatright inlineb" id="plus">+</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

When I click on the first minus ( "-" )  it works correctly.
but for the second, it doesn't work. 
 I want to know how can I automatically chain for all others divs. they have the same typing code.

Also, I would know how can I change the last element (" - ") when an another + is clicked?

Here is a preview of what I want to do

[image]

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/prsebqg3/15/

Comment: Coz your IDs are duplication, and they should be unique. Use class for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic needs to be slightly more complex:

```js
var current = -1;

function handleClick(clicked) {
  $(".w50 p").removeClass("active").find("span").text("+");
  $("#box p").hide();
  if (current === clicked) {
    current = -1;
    return;
  }
  current = clicked;
  $(".w50 p").eq(current).addClass("active").find("span").text("-");
  $("#box p").eq(current).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".w50 p").each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).append($("<span>").text("+"));
    $(this).click(function() {
      handleClick(i);
    });
  });
  $(".w50 p").eq(0).click();
});
```

```css
.w50 {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.w50 p {
  cursor: pointer
}

.w50 p.active {
  color: orange
}

.w50 p span {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: 6em;
}

#box p {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w50">
  <p>What paperwork do I need to complete to file for divorce?</p>
  <p>How do I change my custody and support orders?</p>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <p>Paperwork description</p>
  <p>Custody description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what if he is not using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
it works!
I would know how can I active the span of the first question? ( with the minus, and not the + ) I tried to add " active " class but it doesn't work. I would know and learn about this, I tried since 2hours and all that I managed its show the paragraph of the question.

Comment: @SeanMgd You can simulate a click. Before the very last `});`, insert this: `$(".w50 p").eq(0).click();`

Answer (score 0):

You are using duplicate IDs, which is a no-no. Here is an example using classes and `.querySelectorAll`.

```
var minuses = document.querySelectorAll(".minus");
var pluses = document.querySelectorAll(".plus");

minuses.forEach(function(minus) {
  minus.addEventListener('click', functionHide);
});

pluses.forEach(function(plus) {
  plus.addEventListener('click', functionShow);
});

function functionHide() {
  pluses.forEach(function(plus) {
    plus.style.display = "block";
  });
  minuses.forEach(function(minus) {
    minus.style.display = "none";
  });
}

function functionShow() {
  pluses.forEach(function(plus) {
    plus.style.display = "none";
  });
  minuses.forEach(function(minus) {
    minus.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

You can modify for your particular uses.